# dovecot and postfix from debian repository

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, email-server

I installed `dovecot dovecoot-mysql postfix and postfix-mysql` from `debian repository 7`.

I start them with `/etc/init.d/postfix start` and `/etc/init.d/dovecot start`

but When i use `nmap localhost` I see the following output:
root@sito:/etc/dovecot# nmap localhost

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-09-12 07:35 IRDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000030s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
3128/tcp open  squid-http
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

But when i use `netstat -nap |egrep -i dovecot` i see the folowing output:

```
root@sito:/home/mohsen# netstat -nap |egrep -i dovecot
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     69634    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/anvil
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     69638    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/anvil-auth-penalty
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65456    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/stats
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65459    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/login/ssl-params
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65463    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/replicator
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65467    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/replication-notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65472    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/log-errors
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65476    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/ipc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65478    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/login/ipc-proxy
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65482    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/indexer-worker
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65486    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/indexer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65490    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/doveadm-server
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65494    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/dns-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65496    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/login/dns-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65500    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/director-admin
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65504    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/director-userdb
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65508    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/dict
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65512    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/config
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65514    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/login/login
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65518    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/auth-login
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65522    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65526    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65530    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65534    18414/dovecot       /var/run/dovecot/auth-worker
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     65453    18414/dovecot       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     65452    18414/dovecot       
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    65448    18414/dovecot
```

**My Question** is , Where's `dovecot` ? i don't see its' `ports`....

Comment: check firewall?

Comment: My firewall by default is Open....

Comment: but when i use `netstat -anp |egrep dovecot -i ` i get many result according to `LISTENING` , But `SOCKET UNIX`

Comment: Only installing is not enough, you should configure the services correct.

Comment: Before it, i install such as postfix and see its port such as 143, 110 and so on, Then i start to configure, but i don't see its ports.

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answered your own question by including that netstat output; lines that start with "unix" are unix sockets, not tcp sockets (ports).

As suggested, you need to configure Dovecot before it will actually start and function.

Comment: I installed `dovecot-pop3` and `dovecot-imapd` and the given problem was solved.